# The script does not calculate the median if it is zero in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, lapply

I have the script

```
library(dplyr)
newest=mydat %>% filter(SaleCount > 0) %>%  #First filter out for SaleCount > 0 which of our interest
  group_by(CustomerName,ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear,CustomerType) %>%
  mutate(k = mean(SaleCount[IsPromo==1]),
         m0 = median(tail(SaleCount[IsPromo==0], 5))) %>%  # Calculate m and m0 for all rows
  filter(IsPromo == 1) %>%  # Now keep only rows with IsPromo == 1

   mutate(r = (k-m0)*n())  %>% distinct()
```

This script

```
1. calculate mean value for salecount for 1 category of Ispromo
(without negative value and zero values)
2. for zero category of ispromo , it calculates medians for 5 last obs. by salescount
(without negative value and zero values)
3. than it subtracts median from mean and multiply result on  the count of non-zero and non-negative values for 1 category of ispromo
```

But sometimes the median can be equal =0
like in this example

```
mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 
11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 11712L, 
11712L, 11712L, 11712L), SaleCount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DocumentNum = c(197L, 197L, 
197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 
197L, 197L), DocumentYear = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L), IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CustomerType = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CustomerName = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", 
"SaleCount", "DocumentNum", "DocumentYear", "IsPromo", "CustomerType", 
"CustomerName"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```

In this case code writes `NA` and then it doesn't subtrack median from mean and doesn't multiply.

simple example

```
ItemRelation    SaleCount   DocumentNum k   m0  r
11712             18    197           18    NA  NA
```

How to do that it take into account zero median  and work correct?

## Edited for AAron answer

mean of salescount must be multiply on the count of non-zero and non-negative values for 1 category of ispromo. How to do it?

Comment: `CustomerType`, `CustomerName`  are missing in your example data

Comment: @SeGa, i fixed example, please check edited post.

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem in your logic, not your code; you first say you want the median of the last five values without negative and zero values, but then say the median should be zero. But because of the first, you've removed all the zero values in your filter, so then all the values are zero (when IsPromo=0) and there's no data left to take the median of.

Comment: AAron, yes but in this case , mean for ispromo=1 must be  multiply on  the count of non-zero and non-negative values for 1 category of ispromo. How to do it?

Comment: In your description, though, first you calculate (mean - median) and then multiply. But with no median, what should this difference be?

Comment: if median equal zero, we just  multiply mean on the count of non-zero and non-negative values for 1 category of ispromo.

Comment: Back up though, the median does not equal zero; it doesn't exist! Unless you want m0 to equal the median of all non-zero values, unless there are no non-zero values, and then it should equal zero? That would seem very odd, it would mean that c(1,1,1,1,18) -> 1, but that (0,0,0,0,5) -> 5, even though all the numbers are smaller.

Answer (score 1):

What if you set all NA to 0 and include another `mutate` (`mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))`)?

```
newest=mydat %>% filter(SaleCount > 0) %>%  #First filter out for SaleCount > 0 which of our interest
  group_by(ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear) %>%
  mutate(k = mean(SaleCount[IsPromo==1]),
         m0 = median(tail(SaleCount[IsPromo==0], 5))) %>%  # Calculate m and m0 for all rows
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))) %>% 
  filter(IsPromo == 1) %>%  # Now keep only rows with IsPromo == 1
  mutate(r = (k-m0)*n())  %>% distinct()
```

Which would result in the following:

> ```
>   ItemRelation SaleCount DocumentNum DocumentYear IsPromo CustomerType CustomerName  k m0  r
> 1        11712        18         197         2017       1            1            2 18  0 18
> ```

Comment: Yes, IF the median should be treated as zero in this case; that's not clear yet.

Comment: Yes median should be treated as zero :)

Comment: That would seem very odd, it would mean that c(1,1,1,1,18) -> 1, but that (0,0,0,0,5) -> 5, even though all the numbers are smaller.

Comment: Indeed, the median should actually stay NA, as it doesnt exist in this case. But for this case (subtracting median from mean), I think its ok to treat it as zero if it is not existent or?

Comment: @SeGa, you are right! For this task, it is just condition

Comment: That depends entirely on the logic of your situation and what this `r` value will mean to you. To an outsider, it's roughly the difference between sales with and without promotions, multiplied by the number of days, where days with no sales are ignored completely. Treating it as zero would mean that sometimes I ignore the days with no sales (when there are some non-zero days), and sometimes I don't (when there are no non-zero days). That seems arbitrary, it would seem more appropriate to either always ignore (and then you get NA) or to always include.

Comment: Actually, my two examples (in earlier comment) need a third to be clear; the two above make sense IF we ignore zeros. Where it gets odd is that (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) -> 0 and c(1,1,1,1,1) ->1 but then adding a 5 to each means the one with 0s becomes 5 but the one with 1s stays 1.